# changing div height via media query makes background disapear

Tags: html, css

Hi have a simple div with h1 text that I'm trying to resize for small devices.

```
<div class="sectionTitle" > <h1> title </h1> </div>
```

Whatever I do to lower the height, always makes the white background disappear.

This is after being rendered in freewall - http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/ however height and width are still specified. The text is still visible, just the background disapears.

Any clues how to lower the div height?

```
.sectionTitle
{
    background:         #fff;
    height:             60px;
}

.sectionTitle h1
{
    font-family:        'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight:        300;
    text-transform:     uppercase;
    padding:            22px 20px 0px 20px;
    font-size:          24px;
    word-wrap:          break-word;

}


@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
    .sectionTitle {
            height:             40px;
    }

        .sectionTitle h1{
            padding:            0px 0px 0px 0px;
            font-size:          10px;
            overflow:           hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: The white background is still there on height change [when I use your CSS and HTML](http://jsbin.com/robom/1/edit) (with a red background to make it obvious)

Comment: White background of what? all i see is a red background.

Comment: "*always makes the white background disappear*" - what white background??

Comment: @TJ - This one?... `.sectionTitle { background: #fff; height: 60px; }`

Comment: argh.. i thought the fiddle was from OP... the background is always there i don't see any issue hence voting to close..

Comment: Yes that one. The white background disapears whenever I reduce the height from 60px.

Comment: There's a photgraph behind this. the colour doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @user5839 - because we can't re-create this issue with the HTML and CSS you provided, this question will be closed soon. To prevent that, provide a sample that shows the problem.

Comment: OK I'll try and get it into a fiddle.. it's something to do with the freewall render I think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give width and float to class sectionTitle.

```
.sectionTitl
{
float:  left;
width:  100%;    
background:  #fff;
height:  60px;
}
```

hope this will help you.